# can not safely replay call oracle error on SQL*Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

The data file contains 34576708 rows of data and at the end of the load, in the table there are exatly the same number of rows.
But the loading produces an error:

SQL*Loader-961: Error calling once/load finishing for table PIPPO
ORA-25408: can not safely replay call
SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.
Specify SKIP=31000000 when continuing the load.
Table PIPPO:
  30999999 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  2 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Comment: ORA-25408 is not the main issue, as it only reminds you the query cannot be rollback safely. you should consider `2 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed` and find which 2 rows causes problem.

Comment: There are the first and last one not to load for head and tail. But it stopped at the 31milion's row